# Erro Postgresql com Spring boot - api

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-boot

Opa pessoal
Esto fazendo uma aplicação bem simples mesmo, para ver como funciona o postgresql.
Estou fazendo uma aplicação Spring Api.

Minha classe

```
@Entity
```

public class Produto implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String nome;
private BigDecimal valor;
private int quantidade;
```

restante do codigo

Meu build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}
```

}

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/product
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = 123
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Seguinte erros:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Man, quase 100% de certeza que gradle baixou os drivers corrompidos, eu nao sei dizer ao certo se a importação está correta pois uso o maven. Mas tenta limpar, deletar o pacote, e baixar novamente. E da um confere no properties do postgres, se nao tem nada de errado com os parametros de conexão que tu configurando no properties da aplicação.

Comment: @RodrigoNantes na realidade a aplicação está conseguindo chegar no banco, só falta o esquema ser criado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na sua URL de conexão:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/product
```

A exceção apresentada mais abaixo da sua stacktrace (na sua imagem) deixa isso bem claro: **database product does not exist**

Verifique se a base `product` se encontra criada antes da execução da aplicação, isso não é problema de dependências, ou configuração de entidade.

Comment: Massa
Acredito que seja isso mesmo.
Na verdade achei que com anotação hibernate.ddl-auto: update, ele automaticamente criava o banco com a tabela, assim como no MySQL.
Valeeu

Comment: Ele cria apenas as tabelas :) Geralmente o usuário de banco utilizado na aplicação não tem esse nível de privilégio